# Fisher exact test in R. Why it is row and column order dependent?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a contingency table which look like that:

```
matrix(c(0, 7, 2, 13), 2, 2)
```

So I started to think that those three contingency tables are the same:

```
matrix(c(2, 13, 0, 7), 2, 2)
matrix(c(7, 0, 13, 2), 2, 2)
matrix(c(13, 2, 7, 0), 2, 2)
```

There are only rows or/and columns permutations. According to fisher exact test, I think it is no matter. [Look at the example paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), there is an equation.

Can you explain me why I have different results and I have to correct it by changing alternative argument? Equation's implementation and build in function strange usages is presented below:

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(0, 7, 2, 13), 2, 2), alternative = "less")
fisher.test(matrix(c(2, 13, 0, 7), 2, 2), alternative = "greater")

fisher.test(matrix(c(7, 0, 13, 2), 2, 2), alternative = "greater")
fisher.test(matrix(c(13, 2, 7, 0), 2, 2), alternative = "less")

(factorial(2)*factorial(20)*factorial(7)*factorial(15))/(factorial(2)*factorial(0)*factorial(13)*factorial(7)*factorial(22))
```

Tell me what I have missed from literature please. :)

Comment: direction. However it looks weird because it is a ratio. Note that 1/11.68838 == 0.08555506. All you did is flip the ratio.

Comment: Try `X = rnorm(10); Y=rnorm(10); t.test(X,Y); t.test(Y,X)` Does it make sense that the CI from these t-tests is different? Your estimates are changing but the p-value is not. Same thing is going on here.

Comment: Do you have maybe some links to some materials which can explain me that? I know the idea of CI, but how it is connected with those contingency tables in fisher exact test?

Comment: Why is A/B different from B/A? The estimate/CI offered is the odds ratio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio. Calculate the odds ratio for your matrix, swap the columns then calculate it again pulling from the same positions in your matrix. You will get 1/X of your first odds ratio.

Comment: Continuing subject from your second comment. Why one of them results p-value = 1 and other p-value = 0.4545. does it make sense? 
`fisher.test(matrix(c(0, 7, 2, 13), 2, 2), alternative = "greater")`
`fisher.test(matrix(c(0, 7, 2, 13), 2, 2), alternative = "less")`
If you choose some x from distribution, so P[X < x] + P[X = x] + P[X > x] should be equal to 1, or have I mixed some another important thing?
Sorry for that if it is dummy question, but I am new in that. I am trying to read a lot, but some things looks strange.

Comment: You've got your answer right there: ` P[X = x] `. "Greater" is giving you `P[X>=x]` and "Less" gives `P[X<= x]`. Because the hyper geometric distribution is discrete the distinction matters. Calculate the statistic yourself with `phyper` looking at `<` vs `<=`.